# EntityFramework and Xamarin Forms .Net standard 2.0 Assembly Load issue

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

Potential DUPLICATE [EF.Core 2.0.1 Unsafe in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956433/ef-core-2-0-1-unsafe-in-xamarin-android)
Except targeting 8.0 not 7.1 and dotnet version 2.1.4 is loaded.

Using VS 2017 version 15.5.7 to test [Entity framework in Xamarin forms](https://xamarinhelp.com/entity-framework-core-xamarin-forms/) 
The UWP project. Dont have a mac to test the IOS version.

The droid version dies with the output below
The key points from proj.cs file are

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite">
  <Version>2.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="2.5.0.280555" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" Version="25.4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" Version="25.4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" Version="25.4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" Version="25.4.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" Version="25.4.0.2" />
```

> 03-07 18:19:02.011 D/Mono    ( 5003): Assembly Loader probing
>   location: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'. 03-07 18:19:02.011
>   F/monodroid-assembly( 5003): Could not load assembly
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' during startup registration.
>   03-07 18:19:02.011 F/monodroid-assembly( 5003): This might be due to
>   an invalid debug installation. 03-07 18:19:02.011
>   F/monodroid-assembly( 5003): A common cause is to 'adb install' the
>   app directly instead of doing from the IDE.

Is this issue still not resolved ? [dev com post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/152947/xamarin-android-run-error-could-not-load-assembly.html)

Is there a sample that works on Net standard 2.0 and Android 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue, this will resolve it:

- Go to C:\Users\Your User Name.nuget\System.Runtime.Compilerservies.Unsafe\4.4.0\ and delete the ref folder
- Copy the lib folder and rename it to ref
- Cleanup your Project and Build it

Comment: worked for me, FYI : you must close all vs instances, so that you delete the folder ref.